# proving Pythagoras Theorem in the third dimension using orthogonal projection from a parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra

how can i prove $m^2 + n^2 + o^2 = p^2$ ? given $u = (u1, u2, u3)$ and $v = (v1, v2, v3)$ be vectors that span the parallelogram P

$m$ represents the area of the orthogonal projection in the $xy$-plane 
$n$ represents the area of the orthogonal projection in the $xz$-plane 
$o$ represents the area of the orthogonal projection in the $yz$-plane

Comment: What does $p$ represent?  Is it the area of the original parallelogram created by $u$ and $v$?  Also, what makes you think that it should be true.